# VS Code IntelliSense c_cpp_properties.json Include Path not working

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, unix, fftw

I am trying to make C IntelliSense functional. Tired of the red squiggly line underneath the statement `#include <fftw3.h>` in any of my .c files, I added the following configuration to the `c_cpp_properties.json` file within VS Code:

```json
"includePath": [
   "${workspaceFolder}/**",
   "~/../../opt/homebrew/Cellar/**"
```

For reference, I would compile my files with the following command:
`gcc test.c -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/lib -lfftw3`. My working directory is going to be `/Users/jacobivanov/Desktop/College/CFDG`. Shouldn't this be working, and if not, why?
[image]

@topher217, the following is my C/C++ Log Diagnostics Output:

```
-------- Diagnostics - 2/13/2023, 11:34:17 AM
Version: 1.13.9
Current Configuration:
{
    "name": "Mac",
    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/include"
    ],
    "defines": [],
    "macFrameworkPath": [
        "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
    ],
    "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
    "cStandard": "c17",
    "cppStandard": "c++17",
    "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64",
    "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools",
    "mergeConfigurations": true,
    "compilerPathIsExplicit": true,
    "cStandardIsExplicit": true,
    "cppStandardIsExplicit": true,
    "intelliSenseModeIsExplicit": true,
    "browse": {
        "path": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/include"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
    }
}
Custom browse configuration: 
{
    "browsePath": [
        "/Users/jacobivanov/Desktop/University of Connecticut/Computational Fluid Dynamics Group/1D FFTW Approximation",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/include"
    ],
    "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
    "windowsSdkVersion": "",
    "compilerArgsLegacy": [
        "-o",
        "FFTW"
    ]
}
Translation Unit Mappings:
[ /Users/jacobivanov/Desktop/University of Connecticut/Computational Fluid Dynamics Group/1D FFTW Approximation/approx_1D.c ]:
    /Users/jacobivanov/Desktop/University of Connecticut/Computational Fluid Dynamics Group/1D FFTW Approximation/approx_1D.c
Translation Unit Configurations:
[ /Users/jacobivanov/Desktop/University of Connecticut/Computational Fluid Dynamics Group/1D FFTW Approximation/approx_1D.c ]:
    Process ID: 96358
    Memory Usage: 50 MB
    Compiler Path: /usr/bin/gcc
    Includes:
        /usr/local/include
        /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
        /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
        /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include
        /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
    Frameworks:
        /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
    Standard Version: c17
    IntelliSense Mode: macos-clang-arm64
    Other Flags:
        --clang
        --clang_version=110000
Total Memory Usage: 50 MB

------- Workspace parsing diagnostics -------
Number of files discovered (not excluded): 2649
Number of files parsed: 1053
```

Other suggestions:

- My C/C++ extension was not requiring a restart or reinstall. Both were tried.
- Reset/Restart IntelliSense did not work. Both were tried.
- My new error is `cannot open source file "fftw3.h"C/C++(1696)`
- @Patryk Gawroński, unfortunately, I need to use Makefile for other reasons.

Comment: Why do you use `~/../../opt...` in VSCode if you use `/opt...` for the compiler? And BTW: Does compilig work with that command line?

Comment: @Gerhardh, yes compiling with that command works as intended.

`jacobivanov@Jacob-Ivanovs-MacBook-Air CFDG % gcc test.c -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/lib -lfftw3`

`jacobivanov@Jacob-Ivanovs-MacBook-Air CFDG % ./test`

`hello`

Comment: What's in your makefile? I see you have `configurationProvider` set, which will also try to set include paths based on the Makefile. I wonder if that overrides the others.

Comment: @irowe I checked the makefile, and its compile command was incomplete. I changed it, and the red squiggles disappeared. I'm not holding by breath yet though, for two reasons: (1) IntelliSense has temporarily not acted up before, and (2) this is irrelevant for another file, which had the same problem where the makefile was completely fine.

Comment: I get the red squiggles sometimes when working with Makefiles as well. It seemed to me this had something to do with the recursive glob (i.e. `~/../../opt/homebrew/Cellar/**`). If you specify `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fftw/3.3.10_1/lib` or wherever `fftw3.h` lies you will see the error change from being unable to find `fftw3.h` to one of its dependencies (i.e. something in another folder that should have been covered by the recursive glob). I could always get rid of them by building again from within VScode. Maybe something to do with a cache file.

Comment: I also sometime solved this by Reset Intellisense Database followed by Restart Intellisense on Active File via the command pallet (ctrl+shift+p).

Comment: Some good ideas [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4444) as well. In particular: "do a C/C++: Log Diagnostics command to see how the recursive include paths are getting resolved for a particular file"

Comment: And finally, I've sometimes resolved this by going to the extension pane, and noticing the c++/c extension requires a restart (but didn't tell me otherwise).

Comment: I've also noticed sometimes when I build via the terminal it will create some conflicting cache entries that seem to mess with Intellisense's ability to parse the paths. So deleting the CMakeCache file in your build folder and rebuilding from VSCode can sometimes help.

Comment: @JacobIvanov May I suggest another solution. I see you have Makefile. So let's use compiledb (pip3 install compiledb) and thanks for that you can create compile_commands.json which can by used by clangd and of course if you have clangd extension installed on vs code it should work like charm.